# node.js Socket Transferring overlap

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Connecting c# and node.js through socket.
However, when you receive a socket from the server, you call the socket multiple times, not once.
I don't know why this is. Is there a solution?
This is a brief code for the front desk and server. The full code cannot be disclosed, so it is provided briefly.

c# (Front)

```
private async Task OnConnected(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                string GetMac = GetMacAddress();
                var client = new SocketIO("//IP Address//");
                var loginjson = new JObject();

                loginjson.Add("email", email);

                client.OnConnected += () =>
                {
                    client.EmitAsync("socketlogin", loginjson);
                };

                await client.ConnectAsync();
                await Task.Delay(500);


                client.On("login", async res =>
                {
                    JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(res.Text);
                    LoginCheck = jObj["successLogin"].ToString();

                    await client.CloseAsync();
                });
                await client.ConnectAsync();
                await Task.Delay(200);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Node.js (Server)

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection');

    socket.on('socketlogin', function (data) { 
        var LogInSQL = 'SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email = $1 and password = $2';
        var LogiInValues = [data.email, data.password];

        client.query(LogInSQL, LogiInValues, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                var successLogin = { "successLogin": "fail" };
            }
            if (rows) {
                var successLogin = { "successLogin": "success"};
                }
            });
      });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0enDh.jpg)

Comment: Can you check on "c# (Front)" how many times `OnConnected` is invoked? There are a few things that are red flags to me (maybe it is simply due to the fact that the full code cannot be disclosed): On "Front" a listener is registered on `login`, but that message is never sent from "Server". The "Server" is expecting both `email` and `password` on the `sockerlogin` message, but only `email` is sent from "Front".

Comment: "Can you check on "c# (Front)" how many times OnConnected is invoked? "I don't understand this part. And on the actual code, the email and password are sent in JSON format to read the values correctly from the server. The current code has no problem sending and reading values to the front and server. However, it is a problem because the value has been sent several times.

Comment: What is the expected result? E.g. how many "connection" entries do you expect to see in your log for Server?